# Find the domain of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{(n+x)}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

> Find the domain of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{(n+x)}} $

I've try ratio test for this series, but it doesn't seem to work at all. One thing I know for sure is that by the necessary condition

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{(n+x)}} \space \space \text{converges} \longrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{(n+x)}}=0$$

and

$$\frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{(n+x)}}= \frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{n} \times n^x}=\left ( \frac{n+x}{n}   \right )^n \times \frac{1}{n^x}= \left ( 1+\frac{x}{n}  \right )^n \times \frac{1}{n^x} $$

so the necessary condition above becomes
$$0=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{(n+x)}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( 1+\frac{x}{n}  \right )^n \times \frac{1}{n^x}=e^x \times\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^x}  $$

hence I think $x$ must $> 0$ to make sure that $\frac{1}{n^x} $ approaches to $0$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$

Any recommendation please?

Comment: What are you doing? This is not the form of power series.

Comment: @GGplay If I change my description to "domain of convergence" rather than "radius of convergence", does it make precise sense moreQQ??

Comment: Yes, domain of convergence is fine. At the same time this wrong formulation guided posters in instructive explanations about your error, so you might as well let it as is.

Answer (score 2):

As noticed the series is not in the form of a power series therefore it is meaningless look for the "radius of convergence".

What we can do is study the convergence of the series related to the value of $x$ and since

$$\frac{(n+x)^n}{n^{(n+x)}}= \left ( 1+\frac{x}{n}  \right )^n \cdot \frac{1}{n^x}\sim  \frac{e^x}{n^x}$$

by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac{1}{n^x}$ we can conclude that the series converges for $x>1$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: If I change my description to "domain of convergence" rather than "radius of convergence", does it make precise sense more??QQ

Comment: @mlrofcloud Yes that's fine!

Comment: Sir, doesn't $x \longrightarrow  \infty$ blows up $e^x$ so that the infinite series diverges?

Comment: @mlrofcloud Here $x$ is a fixed real number while $n\to \infty$, so $e^x$ is a fixed real number.

Comment: Excuse me sir I still dont get it. If we include $\infty$ in domain, then $e^{\infty} $ blows up, so the infinite series diverges? Could you please explain more?

Comment: @mlrofcloud Note that $\infty$ is not a number (at least in this context). In this case $x$ is a fixed value such that $M=e^x$ is a fixed (large as we want but finite) number and then as $n\to \infty$ we have in any case $$\frac{M}{n^x}\to 0$$ when $x>0$.